# How to analyze sentence, クラスについてどう思いますか?

Tags: english-to-japanese

クラスについてどう思いますか?

Should this be translated as "What are you thinking of during class?" or "What do you think of class?" I'm having trouble with figuring out how to go about figuring out this sentence.

Comment: I'm not sure also but since Jisho lists  に就いて as a dictionary entry:  に就いて(expression) concerning; regarding​ (usually written using kana alone), I'd guess that is the second "What do you think about class?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, in Japan, クラス usually means a unit of students who study together, not "teaching". So クラスについてどう思いますか? usually means "What do you think of (your) class." For example, an answer would be "私のクラスは、仲が良い(My class are on good terms)".

"Class" in "What are you thinking of during class?" means 授業, so it is translated as "授業中に何を考えていますか?" For example, an answer would be "早くこの授業が終わらないかなぁ、とばかり考えています。(I am thinking that this class will finish soon".

Answer (score 0):

With this expression I understand, "What do you think of the class?"

Because if it meant "What are you thinking about the class?" a diferent verb could be used, like 考える "kangaeru"
So it will be クラスについて何を考えてますか？　
This expresion is more "..what are you thinking".

Answer (score 0):

I understand "What do you think about class?"

クラスについてどう思いますか?

since Nについて means "about N" and どう meaning "what" and lastly 思う meaning "to think", we come to the conclusion that Nについてどう思いますか means "what do you think about N". In this case, N is クラス.

If you want to say what do you think during class I would say something along the lines of:

クラスの間に何を考えていますか。
(During class what do think?)